# Can this jquery function be added a timer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery function that highlights the hovering over an image by changing the opacity of the other non hovered above images. Can it be added a timer, so that the change in the opacity takes a similar motion to fade in fade out? thank you!

```
   jQuery(function($) {
        $('#first img').hover(function() { // on mouseover
            $('#first img').css({'opacity':0.4}); // you can animate this as well
            $(this).css({'opacity':1});
        }, function() { // on mouseout
            $('#first img').css({'opacity':1});
        });
    });
```

Comment: What's that supposed to behave like?

Comment: Use jQuery.aminate() http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: It's so extremely easy and does not require modifying your jQuery. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
jQuery(function($) {
        $('#first img').hover(function() { // on mouseover
            $('#first img').stop().not(this).animate({'opacity':0.4},500); // select all image except the hovered and also stop all previous animations
            $(this).stop().css({'opacity':1},500);
        }, function() { // on mouseout
            $('#first img').stop().animate({'opacity':1},500);
        });
    });
```

**DEMO**

```js
jQuery(function($) {
        $('#first img').hover(function() { // on mouseover
            $('#first img').stop().not(this).animate({'opacity':0.4},500); // you can animate this as well
            $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':1},500);
        }, function() { // on mouseout
            $('#first img').stop().animate({'opacity':1},500);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
        <img src="http://goo.gl/osWLNm" width="100" class="firstimage" />
        <img src="http://goo.gl/umj4bX"  width="100" class="firstimage" />
        <img src="http://goo.gl/W1fumF" width="100" class="firstimage" />
        <img src="http://goo.gl/wMb04Z" width="100" class="firstimage" />
       
    </div>
```

Comment: man that's what i want, however now all images fade, i want the one that is being hovered above to keeps its original opacity

Comment: @mikeb hovered image is keeping it's opacity to 1

Comment: sorry about that it turned out my mistake, just one final question, can the animation speed be controlled?

Comment: @mikeb yes you can pass the second argument to animate function for controlling speed, allowed arguments are number of milliseconds to complete or some strings like slow,fast etc.

Comment: i just noticed that this function sometimes add a blink motion when hovering from an image to another. What could be the problem?

Comment: @mikeb i can't notice this behavior maybe i am missing something but if you can specify after moving from what element to which element it is causing blinking then maybe i can help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81703/discussion-between-mikeb-and-ankit).

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('#first img').animate({'opacity':0.4}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```css
#first img { transition: opacity 0.3s ease; }
```

to your CSS.